# converting code from php to delphi

Tags: php, algorithm, delphi

i have this code in php

```
   function wa_pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false)
{
    $algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
    if ( ! in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true)) {
        die('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.');
    }
    if ($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0) {
        die('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.');
    }
    $hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
    $block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);
    $output = "";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {
        $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);
        $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);
        for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
            $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
        }
        $output .= $xorsum;
    }
    if ($raw_output) {
        return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
    } else {
        return bin2hex(substr($output, 0, $key_length));
    }
}
```

and i want to move this code to delphi, i did it so far

```
    function wa_pbkdf2(password,salt:ansistring;count,keylength:integer;outputraw:boolean=false):ansistring;
var
  hashlength:integer;
  blockcount:integer;
  last:ansistring;
  xorsum:ansistring;
  I: Integer;
  j: Integer;
begin
  hashlength:=Length(THMACUtils<TIdHMACSHA1>.HMAC('',''));
  if frac(keylength/hashlength)>0.5 then //VOLTAAQUI
    blockcount:=round(keylength/hashlength)
  else
    blockcount:=Round(keylength/hashlength)+1;
  for I := 1 to blockcount do
  begin
    last:=salt+ReturnINT32(i);
    xorsum:=StringOf(THMACUtils<TIdHMACSHA1>.HMAC(password,last));
    last:=xorsum;
    res:=last;
    for j := 1 to count-1 do
    begin

    end;
end;
end;
```

how can i make it.

my problem is here

```
$xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
```

i know the `^= is XOR`, but i don't know how to convert this code to Delphi.

Comment: Please stop using AnsiString to hold binary data. Strings are for text. Use a byte array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

delphi is pascal by nature, in pascal xor operator is... `xor`

so your code:

```
$xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
```

will be:

```
last := hash_.....;
xorsum := xorsum xor last;
```

UPDATE:

last and xorsum are strings and php applies xor on strings according following rule:

> If both operands for the &, | and ^ operators are strings, then the
>   operation will be performed on the ASCII values of the characters that
>   make up the strings and the result will be a string. In all other
>   cases, both operands will be converted to integers and the result will
>   be an integer.

similar function in delphi will be something like (writing without actual delphi, possible typos):

```
function xorstring(a,b:ansistring;):ansistring;
begin
    for I := 1 to a.length do
        result[i] = chr(ord(a[i]) xor ord(b[i]));
end
```

UPDATE2:

```
function xorstring(a,b:ansistring):ansistring;
var
i:integer;
begin
    setlength(result,length(a));
    for I := 1 to length(a) do
        result[i] := ansichar(ord(a[i]) xor ord(b[i]));
end;
```

Comment: but xorsum and last is string variable, i don't know how to xor strings.

Comment: @CaioSouzaAndrade xor sum and last are not strings, they are numbers in php, check `$last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);` - here are they converted to numbers

Comment: but when i do var_dump($last) in php, i get this result: string(20) "�_�����14�!���/@L?"

Comment: @CaioSouzaAndrade yep, my fault - php allows xor on strings, which basically xors ascii values of each char

Comment: @CaioSouzaAndrade I've posted update for string xoring

Comment: Please stop using Delphi strings for binary data. Use byte arrays.